# How Javascript array iterator object works?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I saw code like this:

```
let a = 5;

[...Array(a).keys()].map(x => console.log(x));
```

I really want to know how all these things work. I understood that it's mapping over an array and showing output in the console. But I'm confused about what's happening inside this `[]`. How rest operator is working and then finding the corresponding key?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just look at the different steps separately (`Array(5)`, `Array.prototype.keys()`, `...` (spread syntax), `.map()`) -> [JavaScript reference - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/)

Comment: The rest operator is replaced with actual array of values. The array has its map implemented natively.

Comment: Spread syntax (...) allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: *rest* is only the terminus for gathering the rest parameters of a function. or the rest items of an array or with an object the for the left over properties by using a destructuring. *spread* takes an iterable and uses the values as parameters.

Comment: Basically the spread inside the brackets is cloning the return of `Array.keys()`. This kind of technique is used to avoid mutation on the original array. But in this case is totally unnecessary because `map` does not mutate the array and `keys` is creating a new array. This code could be replaced by something like that: `[a].keys().map(x => console.log(x))`. Also, `map` could be replaced by `forEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`...` This is not the *rest* operator, this is *spread* operator (in this situation).
The `Array(5)` creates an empty array with length 5.

`[...Array(5)]` creates this `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`.
At last `[...Array(5).keys()]` creates

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Because the keys of any array in JavaScript (except if the keys have been explicitly modified) are the numbers `0, 1, 2...`.